# Why won't the CIFS service start?

Tags: ldap, samba, cifs, truenas

When I try to enable the **CIFS** service (to use it with my OpenLDAP directory) on my FreeNAS 9.1.1, I get the message

> The service could not be started.

[image]

In the shell of my FreeNAS, I see the following output:

```
smbd[13162]: [2013/09/16 09:53:00.067317,  0] passdb/pdb_interface.c:166(make_pdb_method_name)
smbd[13162]:   pdb backend ldapsam:ldap://10.0.60.136 did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER)
smbd[13162]: [2013/09/16 09:53:00.067414,  0] lib/util.c:1117(smb_panic)
smbd[13162]:   PANIC (pid 13162): pdb_get_methods_reload: failed to get pdb methods for backend ldapsam:ldap://10.0.60.136
smbd[13162]:
smbd[13162]: [2013/09/16 09:53:00.067464,  0] lib/util.c:1221(log_stack_trace)
smbd[13162]:   BACKTRACE: 0 stack frames:
smbd[13162]: [2013/09/16 09:53:00.067538,  0] lib/fault.c:416(dump_core)
smbd[13162]:   dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
```

What could be the problem and how do I get it to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CIFS service is provided through the Samba daemon. To determine why it can't be started, you're best bet is to start it interactively on the shell.

You can use the shell by:

1. Starting the corresponding widget in the web interface:

   [image]
2. Enabling the **SSH** service and connecting to your FreeNAS system with an SSH client:

   [image]

To start the Samba daemon, execute:

```
/usr/local/sbin/smbd --interactive --debuglevel=3
```

Here you might see log messages like:

```
string_to_sid: SID S-1-5-21- is not in a valid format
pdb_init_ldapsam: SID [S-1-5-21-] could not be read as a valid SID
```

In this case, there is a invalid SID in the directory, which causes the Samba daemon to fail to start.